# Mail generated using PHP mail function showing only code

Tags: php, html, email, magento

I have written a code to send mail using PHP mail() function

```
    $message = "
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>TITLE</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <p>Customer ".$customerName." with id ".$customerId." wishes to place order for the following products that are currently note available in stock</p>
            <table>
            <tr>
            <th align='center'>Product Name</th>
            <th align='center'>Product Id</th>
            <th align='center'>Product Part Number</th>
            <th align='center'>Quantity</th>

            </tr>"
            .$content.

            "

            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
";


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
     $headers .= 'From: '.$customerEmail.'' . "\r\n";


    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

The mail is working fine for me, but for the client it appears like this

```
From:
Sent: None
To: orders@xxxxx.com
Subject: SUBJECT

Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8

From: xxxx@xxxx.com
Message-Id: <20140908144611.165ACC36BC@SV08.xxxxxx.com>
Date: Mon,  8 Sep 2014 17:46:11 +0300 (AST)
X-Nonspam: None
X-Antivirus: avast! (VPS xxx-0, 09/09/2014), Inbound message
X-Antivirus-Status: Clean


            <html>
            <head>
            <title>TITLE</title>
            </head>
            <body>


    <p>Customer XXXX with id 3
wishes to place order for the following products that are currently not
available in stock</p>
                <table>
                <tr>
                <th align='center'>Product Name</th>
                <th align='center'>Product Id</th>
                <th align='center'>Product Part Number</th>
                <th align='center'>Quantity</th>



    </tr><tr><td
align='center'>SCREW;BHHS;3/8-16 X .75</td><td align='center'>3237<td
align='center'>35059</td><td align='center'>6</td></tr>

            </table>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Im not understanding why its working for our tests but not for the client. I tested using my gmail account and it shows fine where as the client is using his mail id on his company domain.

Comment: I feel, it's issue of setting might be html content of mail is not enabled for client

Comment: simply restart your test server

Comment: how can i make the html content enabled for client, Ram sharma??

Comment: I think you need to replace double quotes (") with single quotes (')...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of php mail function, I suggest you to use the phpMailer library with google mail smtp credentials. this will help you to send HTML template mails.

Reference URL - [PHP mailer example url](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=examplebgmail)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following header lines

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove  and  tags from your $message. And change headers to

```
$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```